# Getting null values when a class is extended by two other classes

Tags: java, spring, oop, inheritance

I am working on a backend services for a financial company. This application is built using jpos,spring 3.0.5, hibernate 3.6. This application will run in multithread environment which is taken care by jpos. However I confused between which strategy i should use to define a class which properties and data-member can be accessed throughout the application.

**Till now what I have done is:**

```
public class MsgHandler 
{

    public Boolean isOffline = true;
    public Boolean isSuccess;
    public Long mobileTxnId;

    setAllData()
    {
        mobileTxnId=1000;
        ..............
    }
}
```

In this class basically, I used to put all necessary data which i am using frequently throughout the process.  SO I extend the **MsgHandler**

```
public class A extends MsgHandler 
{

    setAllData();
    System.out.println("Mobile Txn Id: "+mobileTxnId) //its printing the values here
    B b=new B();
    b.useData();
}
```

Now an another **class B** is also extending the MsgHandler class, but in class B I am not getting the **null** values of mobileTxnId which is set in **class A**

```
public class B extends MsgHandler 
{
    useData()
    {
        System.out.println("Mobile Txn Id: "+mobileTxnId) //its not printing the  values here
    }
}
```

Why this is happening as I am extending the same class, but in class A , I am getting mobileTxnId but in class B ,I am getting null values for mobileTxnId.

is making **mobileTxnId** static is a good practice, even if the application is going to be used in multithread environment, please suggest me

Comment: `but in class B I am not getting the null values of mobileTxnId which is set in class A` Can you explain that in more detail? Do you mean you *are* getting null values? And why do you think class B should be able to access values from A?

Comment: i guess i am extending the same class, does scope matters here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` and `b` are **not** the same objects, so calling `setAllData()` on `a` object constructor doesn't make the call also in the `b` object constructor.

You need to call

```
b.setAllData()
```

before you use

```
b.useData()
```

Comment: but i dont want to call setAllData() method everytime, i want to use only the values which is set in  class A, how to achieve this in spring or java

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk you can do this only by calling `setAllData` also in the `b` constructor. Also don't use Wrapper classes for primitive types if you don't really need them, they are very slow

Comment: you are not getting my point,here i dont want to call setAllData(), again and again, what if this method is doing some complex data retrival, for example : some kind of data retrival from database, and if I am going to use this extended class many of occasion then  what strategy should i use.

Comment: can i make all fields static? but remember this application is going to be used in multithread environment.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk I got your point, but what you are trying to do is not how inheritance works. And yes, you can use static fields, as a static fields is the same for every instance of the class, but note that if you change the field value in one object, then it will change in every other object of the same type

Comment: okay, but does it will have any ill effect if i use it in multithread environment,because n. no of users going to use this application

Comment: I guess you got my point, actually I want to have class which hold necessary & frequently used data, & then use these data in diffrent part of the application  for each thread.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk Well, if you have to use the same data il every object then yes, it makes sense to have static fields

Comment: but if i mark it as static then there no meaning of extending this class, right

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `b.setAllData()` before the `b.useData()` or calling the `setAllData()` in the initialization block of the `B` class.

So:

```
public class A extends MsgHandler {
{
   setAllData();
   System.out.println("Mobile Txn Id: "+mobileTxnId) //its printing the values here
   B b=new B();
   b.setAllData(); //see what I did here
   b.useData();
}
```

Or:

```
public class B extends MsgHandler {
{
   setAllData(); //see what I did here
   System.out.println("Mobile Txn Id: "+mobileTxnId) //its not printing the  values here
}
```

If this is not an answer to your question, try formulating a different one. It might be that you are actually asking for something completely different (i.e. accessing the values/methods of another class that extended the same, etc)

Comment: here i dont want to call setAllData(), again and again, what if this method is doing some complex data retrival, so would increase extra headache